# Selenium test for Firefox on CloudBees

Tags: firefox, selenium, cloudbees

I'm running Selenium on cloudbees. During the run I am getting the following error:

`Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:  Error: no display specified Error: no display specified  Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time:  System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.34.7-66.fc13.i686.PAE', java.version: '1.7.0_04' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver`

Am I missing anything? I suspect that I need to set something for Display because the Error says `no display specified`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xvnc (or xfvb) to run a headless virtual graphical environment and start browser (firefox and google-chrome are available on CloudBees build slaves). See http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Testing+GUI+applications

Another option is to subscribe to SauceLabs service and user on-demand browsers.

Comment: by the way, the SauceLabs integration with CloudBees is "Free (for now)" http://www.cloudbees.com/platform-service-saucelabs.cb. And they give you a reasonable monthly free tier for testing with, see https://saucelabs.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

FirefoxDriver needs a window to execute tests. The linux machines your test run on don't seem to have windows configured.

Take a look at these links :

- [Link1](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/)
- [Link2](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/04/headless-tests-with-firefox-webdriver.html)

Comment: That 2nd link did the trick for me. I had firefox running fine from the shell, but via selenium it complained about having no display. Setting the DISPLAY using FirefoxBinary fixed it.

Comment: Please at least describe the links, but better include a short version of what the links explain. If the links go dead, your answer becomes useless.